# Splitting an array based on it's first value

Tags: javascript, arrays

hopefully you understand my question.
Lets say I have this array:

```
[[1, 0.3], [1, 0.5], [2, 0.6], [2, 0.7], [3, 0.8], [3, 0.9]]
```

I want new arrays based on the first value like this:

```
[0.3, 0.5]
[0.6, 0.7]
[0.8, 0.9]
```

They are three arrays because there are three numbers 1 and 2 and 3. If there are more numbers, then more arrays should come out.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new object where the key will be the index number(first index of each current array value) and the value will be the relevant numbers (the second index).

```js
var arr = [[1, 0.3], [1, 0.5], [2, 0.6], [2, 0.7], [3, 0.8], [3, 0.9]];

var newObj = {};

arr.map(function(item){
 if(newObj[item[0]])
      newObj[item[0]].push(item[1]);
        else
      newObj[item[0]] = [item[1]];
});

console.log('New object: ' + JSON.stringify(newObj));

// if you insist on creating an array

var newArr = [];
var cnt = 0;
for(var item in newObj)
{
   if(newObj.hasOwnProperty(item))
   {
      newArr[cnt] = newObj[item];
      cnt++;
   }
}

console.log('New array: ' + JSON.stringify(newArr));
```

Comment: but OP want array instead of object

Comment: @Grundy - It doesn't make sense to create an array out of this.

Comment: Possibly, i just not understood what he mean :-)

Answer (score 0):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/yc9b2avu/)

```
var arr = [[1, 0.3], [1, 0.5], [2, 0.6], [2, 0.7], [3, 0.8], [3, 0.9]];
var outputObj = {};
var outputArr = [];
for ( var counter = 0; counter < arr.length; counter++ )
{
   if ( !outputObj[ arr[ counter ][ 0 ] ] )
   {
      outputObj[ arr[ counter ][ 0 ] ] = [];
   }
   outputObj[ arr[ counter ][ 0 ] ].push( arr[ counter ][ 1 ] );
}
for( var id in outputObj )
{
   outputArr.push( outputObj[ id ] );
}
console.log( outputArr );
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answerers that an object containing a set of arrays with keys corresponding to the number you want to group by is the way to go. Here's a solution using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). It passes in an empty object as an initial value.

```
var obj = arr.reduce(function (p, c) {

  // for each of the nested arrays we iterate over
  // set the key as the "groupBy" number
  // (the first element)
  var key = c[0];

  // if that key doesn't exist in the object (p)
  // that we've passed in
  // create it and assign a new array to it
  p[key] = p[key] || [];

  // push the second element of the array to the
  // array in the object
  p[key].push(c[1]);

  // pass the object in to the next iteration
  // of the reduce callback
  return p;

}, {});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dLypr2rj/1/)

Output

```
{
  "1": [ 0.3, 0.5 ],
  "2": [ 0.6, 0.7 ],
  "3": [ 0.8, 0.9 ]
}
```

You can then get the data using square-bracket notation.

```
obj['1'][0] // 0.3
```

Comment: Thanks that was helpful (:

Answer (score 0):

Check for [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sunzhida/tk68p538/):

```
var target = [[1, 0.3], [1, 0.5], [2, 0.6], [2, 0.7], [3, 0.8], [3, 0.9]];
var result = [];
for (var count=0; count<target.length; count++){
  var arrayCount = [];
  for (var elem in target) {
    if (target[elem][0] === count) {
        arrayCount.push(target[elem][1]);
    }
  }
  if (arrayCount.length !== 0) {
    result.push(arrayCount);
  }
}
//This is the result, i.e.: [[0.3, 0.5], [0.6, 0.7], [0.8, 0.9]]
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first element is always non-negative number, something like this also works for you:

```
function merge(arr){
  var tmp = [];
  arr.map(function(item){
    var key = item[0], value = item[1];
    if(!tmp[key]){
      tmp[key] = [value];
    }
    else{
      tmp[key].push(value);
    }
  });

  return tmp.filter(function(item){
    return item ? true : false;
  });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ndaidong/f1g882gy/

Input: `[[1, 0.3], [1, 0.5], [2, 0.6], [2, 0.7], [3, 0.8], [3, 0.9]];`

Output: `[ [ 0.3, 0.5 ], [ 0.6, 0.7 ], [ 0.8, 0.9 ] ]`

Input: `[[1, 0.3], [4, 0.6], [3, 0.8], [4, 0.2], [1, 0.5], [2, 0.7], [2, 0.6], [3, 0.9]];`

Output: `[ [ 0.3, 0.5 ], [ 0.7, 0.6 ], [ 0.8, 0.9 ], [ 0.6, 0.2 ] ]`

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with a value for comparing the group.

```js
var data = [[1, 0.3], [1, 0.5], [2, 0.6], [2, 0.7], [3, 0.8], [3, 0.9]],
    array = [];

data.reduce(function (r, a) {
    if (r === a[0]) {
        array[array.length - 1].push(a[1]);
    } else {
        array.push([a[1]]);
    }
    return a[0];
}, null);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```